# ANT migration tool - fail to deploy to sandbox

Tags: ant, migration-tool, force.com-ide

When I use ANT to deploy to sandbox, I got the following two errors:

```
API Name                        Type                Line    Column      Error Message
Custom System Administrator     Profile Settings    0       0           Unknown user permission: ManageTranslation
Admin                           Profile Settings    0       0           Unknown user permission: ManageTranslation
```

My SF sandbox is Winter 18, API 41.0.

Does anyone know what these errors are and how to get around them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translation Workbench is not enabled. You need to enable in Setup under the Translation Workbench menu. See [Enable and Disable the Translation Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_wbench.htm&type=0) for more details. To get started:

> 1. From Setup, enter Translation Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Translation Settings.
> 2. On the welcome page, click Enable.